# Android 6.0.1 Mysterious "Videos" Taking Up Space

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, insufficient-memory, video, disk-drive

I have been made confused by the Storage Info of my phone since it shows 3.16 GB of videos took up my internal space. But then I checked, the videos not even passed 250 MB in total size.

Can't seem to find the solution in the Internet yet, I've been searching tho. I am using Venus phone by Vestel (a Turkey's made)

Preview:

[image: IMG:]

**Update 1**: The result I got after using Disk Usage app:

[image: IMG:]

**Update 2**: The result I got after using SD Maid app:

[image: IMG:]

**Update 3**: The result I got after using Termux app with first given command:

[image: IMG:]

**Update 4**: The result I got after using Termux app with second given command:

[image: IMG:]

**Update 5**: The result I got after using 'dumpsys' command on my PC connected to my phone by means of USB Debugging:

[image]

**Update 6**: after redo commands of 1st and 2nd but with adding 'grep'

[image]

**Update 7**: result of commands 'dumpsys -l' and 'dumpsys diskstats'

[image]

Comment: it's been days and i think the only way i can get more information of this problem is by rooting my phone

Answer (score 2):

### HOW FILES ARE CATEGORIZED ON ANDROID?

Let's simplify things. You tap a text document, it opens with text editor. You click on a picture, it opens with image viewer. Whether to open a file with a document viewer, or a photo editor, or a media player, or something else, is determined by [MIME type](https://www.howtogeek.com/192628/mime-types-explained-why-linux-and-mac-os-x-dont-need-file-extensions/), or Media Type, or in simple words File Type.

The simple and easy way to determine file type is the ***file extension***; we know a file ending with `.mp4` is a video file. That's how Windows set preferred program to open a file. *NIX operating systems usually rely on ***file's magic*** to determine mime type. That's what [file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command does. Android's [toybox file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/toybox/+/refs/heads/master/toys/posix/file.c) doesn't seem to have a large collection of [magics](https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/magic/Magdir), so the primary source to guess file types on Android is file extensions.

That said, the size of ***Videos*** that appear under ***Internal Storage*** usage details, is the total size of files which have mime type [video/*](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#video), based on *extensions vs file category* [*mapping*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/cmds/installd/MatchExtensionGen.h#23) used by Settings app <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/src/com/android/settings/deviceinfo/storage/StorageAsyncLoader.java#152), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/applications/StorageStatsSource.java#38), [3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/services/usage/java/com/android/server/usage/StorageStatsService.java#377), [4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/Installer.java#272), [5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/cmds/installd/InstalldNativeService.cpp#1716))</sup>. If you think the size shown is inaccurate, you can cross check yourself. Use some app or simply a terminal emulator like Termux to find all *video files*:

```
~$ find /sdcard/ -type f | grep -iE '\.wrf$|\.movie$|\.wvx$|\.wmx$|\.wm$|\.asx$|\.mng$|\.lsx$|\.lsf$|\.mxu$|\.qt$|\.vob$|\.mpe$|\.fli$|\.dv$|\.dif$|\.dl$|\.mpeg$|\.mpg$|\.mp4$|\.m4v$|\.mov$|\.3gp$|\.3gpp$|\.3g2$|\.3gpp2$|\.mkv$|\.webm$|\.ts$|\.avi$|\.wmv$|\.asf$'
```

<sup>* If using Termux, grant [Storage permission](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-setup-storage) to allow `/sdcard` access.</sup>

This will find every file on you storage which is considered video by OS, though one might not be a video in actual and just disguising itself with a video file extension.
To find out individual file sizes and total size, extend the command a bit:

```
~$ find /sdcard/ -type f | grep -iE '\.wrf$|\.movie$|\.wvx$|\.wmx$|\.wm$|\.asx$|\.mng$|\.lsx$|\.lsf$|\.mxu$|\.qt$|\.vob$|\.mpe$|\.fli$|\.dv$|\.dif$|\.dl$|\.mpeg$|\.mpg$|\.mp4$|\.m4v$|\.mov$|\.3gp$|\.3gpp$|\.3g2$|\.3gpp2$|\.mkv$|\.webm$|\.ts$|\.avi$|\.wmv$|\.asf$' | xargs -I {} du -b '{}' | sort -n | awk '{sum += $1} {print} END {print sum}'
```

<sup>* All commands are very basic, usually part of busybox distributions.</sup>

This will show the individual and total file size in bytes. Convert that to MBs or GBs, and that should match the size appearing in Settings. In the same way, you can calculate size of other file types like `audio` and `images`.

The same categorized files can be viewed in the left menu of Android's default `Files` app (at least on Pie). However there could be possible differences. For instance, a file with `.mpe` extension will reflect in videos size shown in Settings, but won't appear under videos of `Files` app or other gallery apps. It's because the *file extension vs mime type* [*mapping*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/media/java/android/media/MediaFile.java#216) which [media scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/218526) uses doesn't include `.mpe` extension in video category. In addition to file extension, media scanner takes [further steps](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/media/java/android/media/MediaScanner.java#101) to segregate files for default apps and [preferred activities](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210168/218526).

Another way to get total size of video files is `dumpsys` [`diskstats`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/services/core/java/com/android/server/DiskStatsService.java#221) service which reads from file `/data/system/diskstats_cache.json`. [DiskStatsLogService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/services/core/java/com/android/server/storage/DiskStatsLoggingService.java#94) runs once every 24 hours when device is idle and charging, and the *extensions vs file category* [*mapping*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/services/core/java/com/android/server/storage/FileCollector.java#81) it relies on is similar to the one used by Settings. So the sizes should be same when `diskstats_cache` file is updated:

```
~$ dumpsys diskstats | grep Videos
```

---

**RELATED:** [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Comment: What else is on your sdcard? Output of `find /sdcard/ -type f | xargs -I {} du -b '{}' | sort -n | awk '{sum += $1} {print} END {print sum}`? Remove any personal data from output if necessary.

Comment: I trima and no result,  just empty at sir

Comment: You don't have a single file in `/sdcard`? How's that possible!

Comment: I myself do dont understand that either. After i pasted the command into Termux then i pressed Enter, it outputted nothing.