# How to remove file from "Recent Files" on android 10?

Tags: privacy, files

In the Files app of stock Android 10 (Pixel 2 XL), there is a "Recent" category. For privacy reasons, I wanted to delete a file in this category. As far as I have searched for this file by filename, and it doesn't seem to exist on my system, but still appears in the list. I've tried clearing the cache/storage for the "Files" app, but it still remains. How can I remove this item from the recent list, clear the entire list, or get the file's folder location so I can delete the real file?

Comment: Try using [app mentioned here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/223643/131553)

Comment: "Files" app in stock Android shows recently modified files (within 45 days) from whole external storage (`/sdcard`) under "Recent" category. A list of all files is built and managed by Media Provider. So you can't remove existing files from "Recent". But if a non-existent file is wrongly indexes in database (`/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db`) you can trigger a media scan or delete data of Media Storage app. See this answer for details: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/218526

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Files** app (`com.android.documentsui`) in stock Android (not that modified by OEMs or custom ROM developers) shows recently modified ([within 45 days](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DocumentsUI/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r39/src/com/android/documentsui/RecentsLoader.java#37)) image and video files (64 each at maximum) from whole shared external storage (`/sdcard` and external SD card) under **Recent** category. A multi-purpose list of all files is built and managed by **Media Provider**. See [how files are categorized based on their extensions](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210294/218526). Apps' private `files` directories aren't scanned by `MediaScanner` but `media` directories are (see [where Android apps store data](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)). Similarly directories starting with a [dot (`.`)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/media/libmedia/MediaScanner.cpp#207) or those having a [`.nomedia`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/media/libmedia/MediaScanner.cpp#142) file and their sub-directories aren't scanned.

So any existing files which are not excluded from scanning cannot be removed from **Recent** category. You may possibly disable the app to hide it from launcher. But the indexed files appear in any app which relies on **Media Provider**, including **MTP**. However if a non-existent file is wrongly indexed in database (`/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db`) you can trigger a media scan or delete data of **Media Storage** app. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/218526) for more details.