# How to clear the Android file chooser history?

Tags: file-system, browser, privacy, file-management, files

When using many different Android apps, a native file chooser is displayed to allow the user to select a file to process.

For example, in the [well-regarded Privacy Browser web browser](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.stoutner.privacybrowser.standard/), visiting the [VirusTotal website](https://www.virustotal.com/) and then pressing the `Choose file` button on that site will invoke this file chooser GUI.

I noticed, on Samsung Android Nougat devices, many of the files listed in the `Downloads` folder were deleted over a year ago, but are still being presented as current options by the file chooser.

**How can one clear the history of this native file chooser?**

When clearing it, are there any undesirable side-effects?

Comment: If you press the "choose file" button on my system the app chooser opens and if I select the "Files" app it starts with the recently used files history. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @Robert I think so. Except I don't get any app chooser... it goes directly to the file chooser.  The file chooser has no `About` menuitem, or any indication if it is from Google or Samsung.  Carefully going through all apps in Settings > Apps (with system apps shown) does not immediately reveal what is actually providing that file chooser GUI.

Comment: @Robert Also, going to Settings > Apps > Default Apps > Set as Default (with `Show system apps` enabled) shows nothing that I find relevant, which is odd.

Comment: [How to remove file from “Recent Files” on android 10?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225743/218526)

Comment: @IrfanLatif I just finished reading your linked answer. Thanks. I tried clearing the cache for `com.android.documentsui`, but doing so (unsurprisingly) had no effect. I'm thinking of clearing its data next. Will doing so result in any data loss of stored files?

Comment: @IrfanLatif I went ahead and took a chance and cleared data for `com.android.documentsui`.  It had no effect either.  Perhaps a reboot after doing that will make a difference.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket As Irfan wrote in the linked answer the recent files list is not populated by the `com.android.documentsui` app itself, instead it is the system-wide `Media Provider`.

Comment: Thanks. I drilled down to several linked answers within the linked answer, and lost sight of that important fact.  That Android media scanner/provider has been problematic since the early days of Android.  When you clear its cache and data, is any data on the device lost?

Comment: No data is deleted but index database is cleared. See the heading ***Solution*** in my answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/218526

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you. Why does a media scanner app need to be run afterwards? Won't the database get recreated automatically after a few hours? (Also the media scanner linked in the Solutions section hasn't been updated since KitKat... is it still a good choice?)

Comment: `com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerService` hasn't been changed since KitKat. So the app should work on new releases too. The same service is called on every boot by `com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerReceiver`. Details in the same answer.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you Irfan.  Interestingly, I tried deleting the cache and data for `com.android.providers.downloads` and `com.android.providers.downloads.ui` before doing anything with the media scanner, and it resolved the issue.  I'm surprised it worked, as I didn't touch the media scanner.